# "Object doesn't support method..." shown in IntelliSense

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a macro for Excel that pulls data from one file, imports it into another, and manipulates it using a custom class. I'm new to writing methods in this context, so I'm guessing this is something stupid and simple, but I've been reading tutorials for an hour now and can't figure it out. Here's the minimal example that replicates the problem:

```
Sub DebugMethod()
    Dim task As New sTask
    Dim this_charge As New sCharge
    this_charge.element = "Testing"
    task.AddLaborCharge (this_charge)
End Sub
```

The function call to AddLaborCharge is what throws "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method." This is particularly confusing because AddLaborCharge comes up as an IntelliSense option when I type 'task.' and it sounds from the other posts like that shouldn't be the case if I haven't defined it properly. Here's the definition of sTask:

```
' Class Module: sTask
Public wbs As String

Dim laborcharge_array As ArrayList

Public Sub AddLaborCharge(charge As sCharge)
    Debug.Print "Adding to laborcharge_array..."
    laborcharge_array.Add charge
End Sub
```

And the (very boring) definition of sCharge:

```
' Class Module: sCharge
Public wbs_element As String
Public nwa As String
Public nwa_title As String
Public name As String
Public element As String
Public post_date As Date
Public hours As Integer
Public log_date As Date
Public labor_cost As Currency
Public nonlabor_cost As Currency
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: There shouldn't be any parentheses in that line.

Comment: Your `laborcharge_array` variable is never initialised.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! BigBen, I had tried with and without the parentheses but I didn't look carefully at the without to see that the error changed. Spectral Instance, all I had to do was add "New" before "ArrayList" and it worked! If you will post those as solutions I'd love to give you credit.